# Webpack with angular 1.x and ES5

Tags: angularjs, webpack

After reading hundreds of lines about browserify vs webpack and several how to of both I decided to go for webpack. The main reason it's because I liked the idea of bundling everything into a js file.

I have an angular project already working and I want to refactor it for webpack. The problem? My project is using  angular 1.4.7, ng-animate and plain javascript (ES5) and all the tutorials and manuals are for ES6. I don't want to refactor my project so much. What's the way to go? I would like an example of each angular module : factory, directive, controller and so on. Many thanks

Comment: I have the same question! Currently I'm working in angular 1.x ES5 project and I don't have permission to refactor it to es6

Answer (score 3):

I typically have a feature.module.js file which has my module definition and requires all of the directives / services contained within the module. Also has the external dependancies.

```js
/* module.js */
angular.module('my.module',['dependancy1', 'dependancy2']);

//External libraries
require('./dependancy1.module.js');
require('./dependancy2.module.js');

//Internal components
require('./thing.directive');
require('./thing.service';
```

```js
       
/* service.js */
angular.module('my.module')
    .directive('yourDir', function myDir(){...});
```

Comment: This seems to be a very good answer, but I feel like it lacks some details, like how the service.js is related with module.js, does it use another require? which one do you require on the main app? Could you please add those details

Answer (score 2):

I'm dealing with the same problem now. And I found something that works (work in progress, but at least I can see progress). My steps:

1. Install [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)
2. Run [this angular-webpack generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular-webpack). Select 'ES5' when asked (the other option is 'ES2015', which I guess is the same that 'ES6')
3. Start modifying the automatically generated boilerplate with your Angular code

Yes, you still need to learn about gulp and sass, but at least you can run a simple AngularJS app using the old ES5 syntax, and start modifying it.

I'm probably blogging about this. So, I'll update this answer then.

Comment: Is that blog post still in the making?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do this:

app.js:

```
require('/any/angular/deps');
var subModule = require('/some/sub/module');

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

// pass the app module in sub modules to allow them to define their own config
subModule.configure(app);
```

`/subModule/module.js`:

```
var someSubDirective = require('./subDir/directive');

export function configure(app) {

   someSubDirective.configure(app);

}
```

`/subModule/subDir/directive.js`:

```
export function configure(app) {
   app.directive('myDir', myDir);
}

function myDir() {

}
```

My idea is to let all sub modules handle their own configuration, so declaring `config` or `constant`, `factories` or `providers`. Letting this then bubble up to the app.js. This means its really easy to delete a folder from your structure, because it is one line removal from it's parent module.

This also makes relevant file paths a lot shorter and easier to handle.

Comment: It is one line edit for deletion, but you have to take care about a lot of cascade dependencies. I think that webpacks encapsulates every module into a closure, but I don't like very much the idea of using `app=angular.module(...` Also I find cumbersome having the requires at the top, and the config calls at the bottom. I'm not blaming your solution, I find it quite good, but I think it is easy to miss some requires or configures and get some headhache